# Unable to load a file based on paramaters passed to rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, yaml

I am unable to load file based on the parameters passed to the rake rask

my code

```
task :update_s =>:environment do
 puts 'enter file name for status'
 file=STDIN.gets
 file="config/status/#{file}"
 license_status=YAML.load_file(file)
end
```

parameter passed is abc.yml but i get a error that

```
No such file or directory - config/status/abc.yml
```

but if i hardcode the file name  (code given below ) it works

```
task :update_s =>:environment do

 license_status=YAML.load_file("config/status/abc.yml")

end
```

I have tried few combination of it none of the worked. Is there a way to load a yml file based on parameters passed to the rake task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `gets` returns the newline character, so `file` is actually `"config/status/abc.yml\n"`

You can remove the newline character with [`chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
file = STDIN.gets.chomp
```